# Redirect user to Log In page if not authenticated in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I know this question has been asked before a dozen times but I cannot figure it out.I'm building a web application in ASP.NET Framework v 4.7.2 and I want to send a user to log in page if the user is not authenticated.This is the controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authenticate(LogInModel lim)
    {
        LogInValidation.Validate(lim.UserName, lim.Password);
        if (!LogInValidation.ValidCredentials)
        {

            TempData["CustomError"] = "Username or password invalid !";
            return RedirectToAction("LogIn");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Sesion");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        if (TempData["CustomError"] != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", TempData["CustomError"].ToString());
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Session()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I validate the user password and username and if they are in the database I redirect them to Session View.If not,I redirect them to the Log in page.I want the user to be able to access the Session page only if it's authenticated.
**What I have tried:**
 I inserted this xml in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogIn" timeout="2880" />
```

and I also added [Authorize] attribute on Session Action.But now if I try to log in I'm always redirected to LogIn page,not to Session.
I also have other pages beside the Log In page that users can access before log in,so blocking all users to access all pages except the log in page at the beginning would not work.

Comment: Sadly, I was not able to understand what you need.

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter they'r session page only after they logged into the application.Basically to see the Session page only after I checked they'r credentials.Right now I can access the Session page directly,even if I'm not authenticated.

Comment: Comparing username and password will only validate the user but after validating the user you need to create user session by setting up Form Auth cookies. Authorize attribute checks based on Auth cookie if user is logged in or not. Since you are not setting the cookie Authorize attribute redirect to login page even after you enter correct login credentials.

Comment: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1229/user-authentication-aspnet-mvc-6-identity

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/forms-authentication-in-mvc/